# Send a sequence of random characters to a com port

Tags: vb.net

I just adquire a cash drawer, connected with a rj11 port to my computer. When i ask about to how to open in my application, they said me to just send a sequence characters at less than 1200 bps to port com5 , beacuse the rj11 is configured to respond to that. How can i send it? I already try this but nothing happens

```
Using COM As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort =
                My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM5")
        COM.WriteLine("Enviodeprueba")
End Using
```

Comment: You probably need to set the baud rate first.  Also there is usually a parity protocol(e.g 8n1) that needs to followed as well.

Comment: You should also verify your PC lists COM5 under the Ports in Device Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know those are the correct baud rate and port number, set those for the serial port first:

```
Dim COM As System.IO.Ports.SerialPort = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
With COM
     .PortName = "COM5"
     .BaudRate = "1100"  'as you stated it has to be less than 1200
     .DataBits = 8
     'and whatever other properties you want to set for the port here
End With
```

Then you have to open the port:

```
COM.Open()
```

THEN you should be able to send info to it:

```
COM.WriteLine("Enviodeprueba")
```

And be sure to close the port when you are done with it:

```
COM.Close()
```

[This is the MSDN article about WriteLine for a port.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)